# Como desplegar mi datepicker hacia abajo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

puse un datepicker en mi pagina dentro de un imput, funciona perfectamente, pero se despliega hacia arriba , como puedo cambiar esa propiedad.

este es el codigo de  javascript

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $( function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({  minDate: 0, maxDate: "+1W", dateFormat: 
  'yy-mm-dd'});
   });
   });
   </script>
```

y asi lo pongo en html

```
      div class="offset-lg-3 col-lg-6 row">
 <div class="col-lg-6 tlBack text-center" style="border-style: solid double; 
   color: white;">
    <span class="label white text-center">date</span>
  </div>
<input type="text" name="datepicker" value="" class="col-lg-6 text-center" 
 id="datepicker" required disabled>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la opcion `orientation: "bottom auto"`.

Tambien tienes `orientation: "bottom left"` que hara que siempre salga en la izquierda del elemento o `orientation: "bottom right"` que hara lo contrario, en este caso a la derecha.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con orientation asi:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $( function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({  minDate: 0, maxDate: "+1W", dateFormat: 
  'yy-mm-dd', orientation: "top"});
   });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: no funciono sigue estando hacia arriba.